# Class accessibility in nested classes

Tags: java

How to access method `getBMW()`, that's located in `private class Model`, without making `class Car` and `class Model` public?

```
class MyCar {
    public Car getCar() {
        return new Car();
    }

    private class Car {
        public Model getModel() {
            return new Model();
        }

        private class Model {
            public String getBMW() {
                //...
            }
            //...
        }
    }
}

class TestCode {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        MyCar car = new MyCar();
        car.getCar(). // <= no method getModel()
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't make any method accessible to the caller if the type itself isn't.

Comment: despite using reflection, which i´d not advise, this won´t be possible. You´d either have to make it `public` or whatever modifier fits you´r access rights, or make `Car` as separate class whom you can access

Comment: The outside world needs to know what a car is before it can do anything with one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't even return the private `Car` from public method, but you could create an interface:

```
public interface BmwModel {
    String getBMW();
}

public interface BmwModelProvider {
    BmwModel getModel();
}

class MyCar {
    public BmwModelProvider getCar() {
        return new Car();
    }

    private class Car implements BmwModelProvider {

        @Override
        public BmwModel getModel() {
            return new Model();
        }

        private class Model implemements BmwModel {

            @Override
            public String getBMW() {
                //...
            }
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working. `Cannot resolve symbol 'Model'`, `interface` is out side the class and the `Model` dose not exit.

Comment: RIght, I didn't notice `Model` was also private nested.

Comment: I've made the changes, but now you can see that the public method `getBmw` has tainted the whole abstract interface structure with "BMW".

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know you wanted the model but maybe this helps.

```
class MyCar {
    public Car getCar() {
        return new Car();
    }
    public Car.Model getModel() {
        return getCar().getModel();
    }

    public String getModelBMW() {
        return getModel().getBMW();
    }

    private class Car {
        public Model getModel() {
            return new Model();
        }

        private class Model {
            public String getBMW() {
                return "BMW";
            }
        }
    }
}

class TestCode {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        MyCar car = new MyCar();
        String model = car.getModelBMW();
    }
}
```

You have to create public methods for all Model methods that you want to access.

Comment: This wont help me. I have nested classes and my end goal is to have `car.getCar().getModel().getBMW()`. I tried using `interface`, but it's not woriking.